# What are my options for authentication for WCF rest?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I am just looking at REST (via WCF for now) which will be used for our Video on Demand system. One of the areas of concern is authentication. We will have clients which will be browser based/mobile (ipad/iphone (iOS)), html5) and desktop apps.

I need a secure mechanism where the user enters their username and password which will be authenticated against LDAP or windows user groups.

Is it a lot of work to implement this in WCF or should I look at some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using basic HTTP authentication over HTTPS will give you this will it not?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any negatives with going with this approach? We are streaming videos so I was wondering if HTTPS will slow things down?

Comment: I also saw a post about Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) and was wondering if there is any mileage in looking at this?

Comment: Well you shouldn't send any authentication information without some form of encryption in play so whether it slows things down (which it will but probably not so that its an issue) is kind of moot

Comment: Is it easy to set up basic http authentication over https? We will have a number of Dealers/Resellers who are not the most technically minded, will it be too difficult for them?

Comment: which side of things are they setting up - server or client?

Comment: Mostly client side. Having thought more about our requirements, we are not really sending any sensitive data that needs to be encrytped except for the username and password. So we do not really need HTTPS for all communications, so can I avoid using HTTPS (even though we will still be authenticating against LDAP)?